# Merger Multiple excel sheets into a common data frame in r excluding a few sheets

Tags: r

Merger Multiple excel sheets into a common data frame in r excluding a few sheets

I have 41 excel sheets in an excel file I need to create a data frame in r using only the first 40 sheets

```
#install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
excel_sheets("scada_data.xlsx")

### 2. Appending 40 sheets into one data frame

excel_sheets("scada_data.xlsx") %>% map_df(~read_xlsx("scada_data.xlsx",.))
mydata<- excel_sheets("scada_data.xlsx") %>% map_df(~read_xlsx("scada_data.xlsx",.))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the below code :

```
library(readxl)
library(purrr)

sheets <- excel_sheets("scada_data.xlsx")
#Keep only 40 sheets
sheets <- sheets[1:40]
data <- map_df(sheets, ~read_xlsx(scada_data.xlsx, sheet = .x))
```